# Alternative creation of new publishing page instance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, publishing-page

I have some custom content type and custom page layout from that content type. This content type has HTML rich text field. And all my contents are page instances of that custom page layout. I need some "Create new" button/web part on the default page of the site, to give the content authors ability to create new content without going to standard sharepoint page creation process.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? How to create the button, how to check permissions, how to create the page, ...

Comment: I wonder how to do that, i think it is not possible OOTB. So needs custom development but how? I need some enlightments & ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which part is your problem so here is some helpers:

To security trim a bit of HTML use [SPSecurityTrimmedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol.aspx)

To make your page layout default (or only allowed) click 'Page layouts and site templates' in the 'Look and Feel' section of site settings

To launch the Create Page dialog use the following JavaScript:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+'_layouts\u002fCreatePublishingPageDialog.aspx', null, 390)
```

To create a Publishing Page using code use [PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee562149.aspx)